# Find the drag coefficient from a ln(acceleration) v time graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, drag

I don't have a huge amount of information to go on, but I basically have the decay of a pendulum v time, and then taking the decay of this graph, I have a plot of ln(Theta max) v time. From this I somehow need a method to find the drag coefficient of the mass on the pendulum. Some pointing in the right direction would be a massive help.

[image: Oscillation v time]

[image: Log of Theta v time]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: This isn't a homework question. I working on a project and want to know if I'm heading in the right direction or if I need to rethink my plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fit the graph to the equation for z(t), under "Driven harmonic oscillators" in the Wikipedia article given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator.  When you do that, you can calculate "Q", and use that to estimate the drag coefficient.

Now, for a guess regarding your solution.  The damped sinusoid given in the graph clearly indicates that the damping force is linear.  It would be wise to estimate the maximum Reynold's number for this situation to ensure that your pendulum bob stays within the region of laminar flow, as turbulent flow produces a retarding force that is proportional to the square of velocity (a quadratic relationship).

Comment: I think I can work with this, I'll have a play about and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like this is heading me in the right direction! Thanks for the help.

Comment: CM92, you're welcomed.